# Installing distributed xgboost will manipulate the huge dataset ?

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

I have a dataset about 40G and my mac only has 16G memory. I want to run xgboost on my dataset.
It seems that mac can not load it directly into memory.
Using the distributed xgboost will handle the 40G dataset on my mac ? Any advice about how to handle my dataset ? Thanks.
(I have already transform the original csv file to libsvm format, but the size is still over 40GB ).

Comment: Did you try loading the file using external memory?  http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how_to/external_memory.html

Comment: Thanks. Let me try. I am not fully understand the mechanism of loading from external memory. Does it mean that the dataset just exits in disk and when calculating, part of the data will loaded into in-memory which is like spark ?

Comment: Yes that's external memory.